# Validating data in excel sheet

Tags: excel

I have a requirement to validate the data in excel and display the rows with  problematic data. The excel may have 1000 rows and 40 columns. Could you please let me know whether we have any framework to validate all the data in excel? I need to validate all the 1000*40 cells and display the row numbers which is having issues or is it better to use apache poi parse the data and validate each cell?

I need to do different kind of validation for each columns, like some column it should be numeric and length should be between 1-50,for another columns the it should have only a list of value("ABC", "BCD") etc. For each column the validation is different

Comment: Can you please elaborate what kind of validations do you need to do?

Comment: I need to do different kind of validation for each columns, like some column it should be numeric and length should be between 1-50,for another columns the it should have only a list of value("ABC", "BCD") etc. For each column the validation is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the spreadsheet as understandable and hence maintainable as possible, I would introduce a separate validation column for each of the 40 data columns.

For instance, I'd put the label "Validate Col A" into cell AP1 (i.e. at the top of the 42nd column) and underneath that use a formula like `=if(<A2 is valid>,0,1)`. Of course you will have to replace `<A2 is valid>` with a real validation expression for that particular column, and then  copy the formula downwards. Use col AQ to validate col B in a similar way, etc. All of those columns can then be hidden if you like.

Then use col AO to combine all the pieces of validation together, with the formula `=sum(AP2:CD2)`. When that formula is copied downwards, any value greater than 0 indicates a row with a validation error.

Once you get that working, you could add a filter to col AO and use it to hide any rows where the value is 0.